# process AJAX post with unknown number of variables in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form on my website. The questions are stored in the database and some variables determine which questions you see. Thus, the number of questions is unknown. The code for the questions is like this:

**HTML**

```
<ol class="questions">
<?php
$number = 1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<li>';
            echo '<span><label for="q'.$number.'">'.$row['question'].'</label></span>';
            echo '<input id="q'.$number.'" name="q'.$number.'" type="text" value="'.$row['description'].'" onclick="this.value="";this.onclick="test";this.style.color="#000000"; setAttribute("type", "text");" onfocus="if (this.value == "'.$row['description'].'") {this.value = ""; setAttribute("type", "text");}"   onblur="if (this.value == "") {this.value = "'.$row['description'].'";setAttribute("type", "text");}"/>';
        echo '</li>';
        $number++;
};?>
```

Now, with some help I created the follow AJAX post.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "mailer.php",
    method: "post",
    data: $("#theForm").serialize()
});
```

How can I process this in PHP with an unknown number of questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mailer.php

```
    $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
               'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
               'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    if(!empty($_POST)){
        foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
            $message .= "\n".$key.":".$val;
        }
    }


    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

See php mail(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option: Use PHP's "array" syntax in the form, instead of hardcoding your numbers into the field name:

```
<input name="q[1]" value="foo" ...
<input name="q[2]" value="bar" ...
etc..
```

and then

```
$_POST['q'][1] -> foo
$_POST['q'][2] -> bar
```

If you can't rewrite the form, then:

```
$field_names = preg_grep('/^q\d+$/', array_keys($_POST));
foreach($field_names as $field) {
   $val = $_POST[$field];
   ... do whatever you have to
}
```